# Access private variables within public variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constants, private, public

I'm building a site on the mvc3 (and loving the new syntax!). I am creating email functionality by using constants.  However, I am at a loss about using public properties / constants with it. I know that with WebForms we could add a public property in code behind. But I am struggling with do this.

```
 public const string ImportantNoticeForEmployers =
            @"<span style=""font-size:12px;line-height:1.5"">" +
            @"<b>Important Notice for Employers<b><br><br>" +
            @"The Information on xxxxxxxxxxx<br><br>" +
            @"</span>";

  private const string EmployerDisclaimer =
           @"<span style=""font- size:13px;font-family:arial,sans serif;line-height: 1.5"">" +
           @"<b>::Disclaimer::</b><br><br> " +
           @"By your positive acts of registering on xxxxxx.Login details are required to delete the account)" +
           @"</span";
```

I have to call this private method each public method. Can anyone help me this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show code how you want to use your constants? Its not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: I gave my code above. Actually each email send with disclamer. I have many methods like "ImportantNoticeForEmployers".Each method should have the disclaimer. If i write the disclaimer text each method means it is redundancy. It is not efficient. so I create private method and try to just call inside the public.....But I can't. Hope you understand